# Create bundle to use a secondary entity manager with a different connection

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am creating a bundle which is meant to pull data from a secondary database. I'm not sure what other configurations I can add or change to make this work. I tried passing in the connection directly into the repository also. Ideally a tool using the bundle would just be able to pass the repository as parameters and easily use it.

### The error given:

`The class 'SRC\SRC\DataBundle\Entity\Course' was not found in the chain configured namespaces`

`doctrine.yml` file within the tool that is importing the bundle. SECONDARY_DATA is the one I am trying to connect my entity manager to

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                # configure these for your database server
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.6'
                charset: utf8mb4
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
                url: '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'
            SECONDARY_DATA_CONN:
                # configure these for your database server
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.6'
                charset: utf8mb4
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
                url: '%env(SECONDARY_DATABASE_URL)%'

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                auto_mapping: true
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    App:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity'
                        alias: App
            SECONDARY_DATA:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                connection: SECONDARY_DATA_CONN
                auto_mapping: false
```

`services.yml` file of the main tool. I changed some of the paths and names for privacy reasons.

```
  SRC\SRC\DataBundle\Entity\Repository\CourseRepository:
        alias: 'src.src.data_bundle.course.repository'
```

`services.yml` file for the bundle

```
services:
    src.src.data_bundle.course.repository:
        class: SRC\SRC\DataBundle\Entity\Repository\CourseRepository
        factory: ['@doctrine.orm.SECONDARY_DATA_entity_manager', getRepository] # where i believe the entity manager will know to use the correct database
        public: false
        arguments:
            - 'SRC\SRC\DataBundle\Entity\Course'
```

The repository file

```
namespace SRC\SRC\DataBundle\Entity\Repository;

use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;

class CourseRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{}
```

Comment: You will have to add a mappings section to your SECONDARY_DATA configuration.  Once it is properly configured, that should be all you need.  The ServiceEntityRepository will actually iterate over all of the configured entity managers and see which one maps your Course entity.   Should all happen automatically.  Actually, unless your bundle is using autowire, you want your CommentRepository to extend EntityRepository and then use your service factory definition to inject the correct entity manager.

Comment: @Cerad thanks for the response, I can probably figure out the mapping. How do I know if my bundle is using autowire?

Comment: It would be set in the _defaults section of your bundle's services.yml file.  But normally, bundles do not autowire.

Comment: I prefer to inject the `ManagerRegistry` to services, then have the service get the EM it needs using `$managerRegistry->getManager($emName)`; Then you would just have to pass the name of the EM (i.e. `SECONDARY_DATA_entity_manager`) to your service. I'm not sure if one approach is better than the other, but thought I would mention this as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

This was how I ended up solving it using the mapping on the ORM entry

```
SECONDARY_data:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                connection: SECONDRARY_data_CONN
                auto_mapping: false
                mappings:
                    DataBundle:
                        type: annotation
                        prefix: UCI\AWT\DataBundle\Entity
                        dir: "%kernel.project_dir%/.../.../data-bundle/Entity"
                        is_bundle: false
```